# Python - Facial Tracking H.264 video leads to extensive Lag and errors

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, h.264, video-processing, video-encoding

Can someone help me with this one ? I have written this code in Python to perform facial tracking on a HD IP Camera feed using the H.264 format. The script works as it should except:

1. When I execute the program I get these error messages but then the video loads up.

   [h264 @ 000000000031af80] Missing reference picture, default is 0
   [h264 @ 000000000031af80] decode_slice_header error
   [h264 @ 00000000093768a0] Missing reference picture, default is 0
   [h264 @ 00000000093768a0] decode_slice_header error
2. The video is extremely slow with a 5-10 second lag per frame. However, If I remove the facial tracking segment the video is smooth as it should but then without facial tracking the entire purpose is defeated. I was also thinking of using multiprocessing so that I am able to speed this process up, but I want to be doubly sure that there is no other way before I head onto that route.

Please if someone could help me out.

=============================

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade_face.xml')

# Function to Track Face
def facetrack(frame):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        print ("X = %s and Y= %s" %(x,y))

# Capture video from an IP Camera - FOSCAM
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/videoMain")

# Extract Frame and perform Facial Tracking
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    facetrack(frame)
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale is an expensive computation. What resolution does your image have?

Comment: I am running it on 640x320 or 720p at 30fps. Both give the same lag.. I am not use any library such as live555 or ffmpeg... do you think that could be the reason ?

Comment: try to use a lbpcascade instead of the haar one.